# How to pull data from MQTT broker in host OS?

Tags: virtual-machine, mqtt, mosquitto

I'm publishing my data through MQTT in a Windows 10 Virtual Machine via specific IP, hosted by Ubuntu 18.04 and I'm trying to save this data on my host OS. I created a bridge between the host and the guest OS so my guest can be seen by the router (My host receives Ping from my guest and the guest is at the same subnet mask as my host).

I can see the data in the MQTT-Lens in my host machine at the same IP by subscribing to the topic. I wrote a script to save the data. The script is working just fine if I manually publish some data. But it's not subscribing to the same network while I'm publishing data from my guest OS.
Does anyone have any idea? How can I make sure I'm addressing the same broker in my host and guest OS?

Comment: You don't subscribe to a network, your clients need to be all connecting to the same broker, as long as all clients can connect to the broker it should just "work"

Comment: Thanks. I am receiving ping and packets in the host. So, this rules out the network problems. In fact, I realized that I was using the same client IP for both clients in host and guest. :)